# $L_2$ convergence maintains the sign

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $X$ a finite dimensional space such that $X\subset H^1.$ Let a sequence of non-negative functions $f_n\in X,\,n\geq1$ and a function $f\in H^1$ such that
\begin{equation}
\|f_n - f\|_{L_2} \to0,\;\;\;n\to \infty.
\end{equation}
It is sufficient to conclude to the fact that $f\geq0?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $L^{2}$ convergence implies almost everywhere convergence for some subsequence. Hence $f \geq 0$ a.e.

Comment: And if you don't want to appeal to this result, if $f$ is negative on a set of positive measure, then the $L^2$ difference between it and $f_n$ would not be boundable by any arbitrary $\varepsilon$.